# D3 + Leaflet: d3.geo.path() resampling

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, leaflet

We've adapted Mike Bostock's original D3 + Leaflet example:
http://bost.ocks.org/mike/leaflet/
so that it does not redraw all paths on each zoom in Leaflet.

Our code is here: https://github.com/madeincluj/Leaflet.D3/blob/master/js/leaflet.d3.js

Specifically, the projection from geographical coordinates to pixels happens here: 
https://github.com/madeincluj/Leaflet.D3/blob/master/js/leaflet.d3.js#L30-L35

We draw the SVG paths on the first load, then simply scale/translate the SVG to match the map.

This works very well, except for one issue: D3's path resampling, which looks great at the first zoom level, but looks progressively more broken once you start zooming in.

Is there a way to disable the resampling?

*As to why we're doing this:* We want to draw a lot of shapes (thousands) and redrawing them all on each zoom is impractical.

**Edit**
After some digging, seems that resampling happens here:

```
function d3_geo_pathProjectStream(project) {
   var resample = d3_geo_resample(function(x, y) {
     return project([ x * d3_degrees, y * d3_degrees ]);
   });
  return function(stream) {
    return d3_geo_projectionRadians(resample(stream));
  };
}
```

Is there a way to skip the resampling step?

**Edit 2**

What a red herring! We had switched back and forth between sending a raw function to `d3.geo.path().projection` and a `d3.geo.transform` object, to no avail.

But in fact the problem is with leaflet's `latLngToLayerPoint`, which (obviously!) rounds point.x & point.y to integers. Which means that the more zoomed out you are when you initialize the SVG rendering, the more precision you will lose.

The solution is to use a custom function like this:

```
function latLngToPoint(latlng) {
  return map.project(latlng)._subtract(map.getPixelOrigin());
};

var t = d3.geo.transform({
    point: function(x, y) {
      var point = latLngToPoint(new L.LatLng(y, x));
      return this.stream.point(point.x, point.y);
    }
  });

this.path = d3.geo.path().projection(t);
```

It's similar to leaflet's own `latLngToLayerPoint`, but without the rounding. (Note that `map.getPixelOrigin()` is rounded as well, so probably you'll need to rewrite it)

You learn something every day, don't you.

Comment: You would have to modify the source.

Comment: Have you tried simply changing the return to `return d3_geo_projectionRadians(stream));`, leaving out the resample?

Comment: Hi Lars, a little good night's sleep does wonders! The problem was with my Leaflet part (see Edit 2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Coincidentally, I updated [the tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/leaflet/) recently to use the new [d3.geo.transform](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Streams#wiki-transform) feature, which makes it easy to implement a custom geometric transform. In this case the transform uses Leaflet’s built-in projection without any of D3’s advanced cartographic features, thus disabling [adaptive resampling](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3795544).

The new implementation looks like this:

```
var transform = d3.geo.transform({point: projectPoint}),
    path = d3.geo.path().projection(transform);

function projectPoint(x, y) {
  var point = map.latLngToLayerPoint(new L.LatLng(y, x));
  this.stream.point(point.x, point.y);
}
```

As before, you can continue to pass a raw projection function to d3.geo.path, but you’ll get adaptive resampling and antimeridian cutting automatically. So to disable those features, you need to define a [custom projection](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5663666), and d3.geo.transform is an easy way to do this for simple point-based transformations.

Comment: Hi Mike, thank you for the answer! We had indeed tried this version as well, but since it didn't work I assumed it's still a matter of resampling... turns out the problem was my with Leaflet part. (see my Edit 2).